# chef windows_package options to check box

Tags: windows, imagemagick, chef-infra, inno-setup

Trying to install ImageMagick on a Windows server 2008 R2 machine in a Chef recipe.

Works perfectly with the following recipe

```rb
windows_package 'install imagemagick' do
    action :install
    source 'http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-7.0.3-5-Q16-x64-dll.exe'
end
```

However I'm missing an important part.

When I run the installer on the machine, I'm give some additional tasks with the install (see image below).  I need the **Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)** option checked.

Can I do this in a Chef recipe?

[image]

I know [windows_package](https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_package.html) has the `options` that could handle this, but how to I figure out what to put for that option?

Comment: I assume that [`/COMPONENTS`](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/windows.html) could help you. I just wasn't able to figure out how the legacy "component" is actually called.

Comment: Given the [chocolatey 'imagemagick' package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/imagemagick.app) (see `tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1`), it could also be `/MERGETASKS=legacy_support`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@StephenKing correctly commented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40430549/850848#comment68110499_40430549), use the [`/MERGETASKS=legacy_support` command-line switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=MERGETASKS).

To find this out, you do not have to go to a source code.

- Run the installer with the `/?` to find out [its command-line switches](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline).
- Run the installer with the `/SAVEINF=path` to get it save its settings to an INI file. If you check the task you want (*"Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)"*) during the installation, you will see this directive in the INI file:

  ```
  Tasks=desktop_icon,modifypath,legacy_support
  ```

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: To clarify, in my recipe, I added `options '/MERGETASKS=desktop_icon,modifypath,legacy_support'`