# How to create desktop icon while installing mtputty using chef?

Tags: chef-infra, inno-setup

I have been trying to install MTPuTTY.exe file on Windows 10 using CHEF. Based on other references I got from stackoverflow, I was able to understand the type of installer and the command line switches associated with the installer. Please find details below :

Application : MTPuTTY.exe (1.6 Beta)
Installer Type : inno
Command line arguments/usage : /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /SP-

When I run a silent install manually on the system, it creates the desktop icon, however the same command doesn't create the desktop icon when ran through chef client. I even ran the command using /SAVEINF and I got to see it as  :

```
Lang=default
Dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\MTPuTTY
Group=MTPuTTY
NoIcons=0
Tasks=desktopicon
```

So, I used recipe as

`windows_package 'MTPutty 1.6' do
  source "http://webserver.local/mtputty/1.6/MTPuTTY_setup.exe"
  installer_type :inno
  options "/SP- /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /SAVEINF=mtputty_information /TASKS=desktopicon"
  action :install
  ignore_failure true
end`
It installs the application, but no desktop icon.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong ? Can anyone help me on this ?

NOTE : I have referred this post as well [chef windows_package options to check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430549/chef-windows-package-options-to-check-box)

Thanks and Regards,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Probably just use the [`windows_shortcut` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_shortcut.html) to create one yourself in your recipe code.